# In Rust, why `void*` is `*mut c_void` not `*mut ()`? Could I use `*mut ()` to represent a `void*` address safely?

Tags: rust, void-pointers

In rust, `void` is (), but `void*` is a pointer of an enum

```
#[repr(u8)]
#[stable(feature = "core_c_void", since = "1.30.0")]
pub enum c_void {
    #[unstable(
        feature = "c_void_variant",
        reason = "temporary implementation detail",
        issue = "none"
    )]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    __variant1,
    #[unstable(
        feature = "c_void_variant",
        reason = "temporary implementation detail",
        issue = "none"
    )]
    #[doc(hidden)]
    __variant2,
}
```

Could I use `*mut ()` to represent a `void*` safely?

Comment: void can't really be represented in rust, that as much why zero type can't be represented in C, but in Rust is allowed. in Rust void is not `()`, void is nothing it can't be anything, () is a empty tuple not nothing. you CANT construct a void in C, the only thing you can do is convert some pointer to a void* that and do the reverse, but that all. the best in rust would be the impossible type `!`

Comment: We like to think of `void` in C like a unit type, both because it makes sense mathematically and because languages like Scala and Rust explicitly make it so. But unlike in Scala (where the mathematical comparison is fully correct), `void` in C is an awkward kind-of-empty, kind-of-not type. An argument of type `void` can never be passed, but a value of type `void` can be implicitly returned. In any conventional type system (think Hindley-Milner, for example), a type with those properties is absurd. Hence, it's really something fundamentally different (and more bizarre) than Rust's unit type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: `void` creates so much woes in "generic" (macro/templates) code. It can be returned, even chain returned (`return foo();` with `void foo();`), but cannot be stored in a variable :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. but no, a function that return void, doesn't in reality, the function return nothing, not something call void. It's a keyword not a real type